# Relates to spreadsheet in google docs

Tags: google-sheets

=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(FILTER(SPLIT(IMPORTDATA("https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.TXT"),CHAR(10)),isnumber(left(SPLIT(IMPORTDATA("https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.TXT"),CHAR(10)),2)*1)=true,SPLIT(IMPORTDATA("https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.TXT"),CHAR(10))<>""),";"))

This is what i use to get the data from the website and split it into different columns.

It works on some days and fails on other days with #N/A error mentioning "could not fetch URL"

Is this a website issue or this command needs further correction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Copy/pasting text or adding garbage to your post to bypass the quality requirements is a violation of site policies, and doing so may lead to suspension of your account. It's also an insult to the millions of people who respect this site for the quality resource that it remains. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: That is not certainly not my intention and my question is genuine and not copied or pasted. I did go through help and could not locate what i needed. Maybe my looking for help is not that good since i am new to asking questions.

Comment: I realize you're new. Thank you for removing the text that you had copy/pasted. I still suggest that you follow the links I provided to improve your experiences here. There's an entire section on [ask] to help you ask questions here.

Comment: `fails on other days with #N/A error mentioning "could not fetch URL"` On the days that the url fails, does the "manual" download from the site (`Latest NAV>NAV DOWNLOAD>Download Complete NAV Report in Text Format`) also fail?

Comment: No. The manual download works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting the url, it looks like you are importing almost 13K of rows for each **IMPORTDATA** calls.
Depending on your setting, sheet will recalculate each after edit or whenever the sheet is reloaded and URL calls are a bit limited and may cause the error described.

Solution is to remove the formula every after import, ***or*** create a google sheet script you can execute with a button.

```
function txtImport() {
  const url = "https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.TXT";

  const fetch = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const resp = fetch.getContentText();

  const ssh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  let splitResponse = resp.split("\n");

  if (splitResponse.length > 0) {
    let headr = splitResponse.splice(0, 1)[0].split(";");
    ssh.getRange(1,1,1,headr.length).setValues([headr])
    ssh.getRange("A2:F").clearContent()
    SpreadsheetApp.flush()
    let allData = []
    splitResponse.forEach((sp,ind) => {
      if (sp.includes(";")) {
        let vals = sp.split(";");
        if(vals.length>0){
          allData.push(vals)
        }
      }
    })
    
    ssh.getRange(2,1,allData.length,allData[0].length).setValues(allData)
  }
}
```

Just replace the **.getSheetByName("Sheet2")** with the sheet name.

**Output**:
[image: output]

Comment: I don't understand this much; Do i need to create a sheet script? Or should i first get the data in a new sheet and then run the script? Need spoonfeeding.

Comment: You can start with a blank sheet. You will only need the name. Each time you run the script, it will clear the content to get new data.

Comment: @Ramadurai start with a blank sheet, replace the "sheet name" in the code I highlighted above. You can google how to call a function using a button so you can execute the code without opening the AppScript. Try it, then let me know where you stuck

Comment: Followed your instructions and the script you gave here works fine as of now. 
If i run into any issues i shall revert here.

Thanks.